# Entity FrameWork Code First атрибут альтернативного ключа

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток, хочу в бд для полей задать составной альтернативный ключ, как это можно провернуть через атрибуты Entity Framework? Есть еще мысль попробовать через миграцию, но предпочтителен через атрибуты, поиск не дал наличия такого атрибута, может плохо искал?

ps. EF6, .Net, C#, code first

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx про Fluent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) сказано:

> Alternate keys can not be configured using Data Annotations.

Перевод от меня:

> Альтернативные ключи не могут быть настроены с помощью аннотации
>   данных, т.е. атрибутов.

Поскольку Вы используете Code-First, то рекомендую попробовать Fluent API.

Приведу пример по настройке одного свойства с помощью Fluent API^

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasAlternateKey(c => c.LicensePlate);
    }
}

class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Полный список атрибутов поддерживаемых EF:

- [KeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute)
- [StringLengthAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute)
- [MaxLengthAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute)
- [ConcurrencyCheckAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute)
- [RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute)
- [TimestampAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute)
- [ComplexTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.complextypeattribute)
- [ColumnAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute)
- [TableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute)
- [InversePropertyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute)
- [ForeignKeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute)
- [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute)
- [NotMappedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute)

Comment: На сколько я почитал и попробовал, данный вариант подходит для EF core, а в EF6 во первых нет класса ModelBuilder (он теперь называется DbModelBuilder ), и у него нет метода HasAlternateKey. По поводу альтернативных ключей есть [записи](http://dotnet.today/en/entity-framework-7/modeling/relational/unique-constraints.html#alternate-keys-unique-constraints) что в EF7 будет реализовано. А пока видимо реализую через составной первичный ключ, чего не хотелось бы